# How to create a shortcode for Admin Theme Option - Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode for 2 of my theme's options. Basically I want to grabe my theme options to my shortcode so that I can display them anywhere on my posts something like this:

```
[ads_1] 
[ads_2]
```

However when I tried to get the options on my shortcode it wont work at all and its giving me an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'theme_settings' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\themewp\wp-content\themes\bots_final\shortcodes.php on line 86

Here's my snippet for my shortcode where in I am trying to grab my theme option data:

```
add_shortcode('ads_1', function($atts){
    return '
    <div>
        <?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
        <?php echo $options['banner1']; ?>
    </div>';

});
```

I am trying to grab the options from my Theme options page. Check my theme options code:

```
<div>
<?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
<?php echo $options['banner1']; ?>
</div>
```

Any idea what's the problem why I can't grab it?

Comment: check syntax of your code. in your code you are mismatching comma's. first you have to clear that issue.

Comment: Can you please replace my code? and correct it?

Comment: See my code and try it

Answer (score 0):

You opened the `<?php` inside an open php tag:

```
add_shortcode('ads_1', function($atts){
  $html = '<div>';
  $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' );
  $html .= $options['banner1'];
  $html .= '</div>';
  return $html;
});
```

What do you get from `get_option( 'theme_settings' );`? It seems like your suggesting an array..
To avoid conflicts, I'd store your settings as `'mytheme_theme_settings'`.